# Is my graphics driver and opengl properly installed?

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, opengl, qt

I got some suspicious outputs related to graphics and opengl while looking around an install of Debian 9.12 64 on ThinkPad X200s. Perhaps you guys can tell me if the following looks fine?

I tried to run one [example from Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-bars-example.html) and looks like OpenGL content isn't being displayed. Why?

[image]

First I used lshw and lspci:

```
*-display:0
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 07
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:31 memory:f2000000-f23fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
     description: Display controller
     product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2.1
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
     version: 07
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:f2400000-f24fffff
```

-

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
        Memory at f2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at f2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
```

-

And from glxinfo:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo | grep version
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/strieder/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 8086:2a42, driver i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/strieder/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Using DRI3 for screen 0
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/strieder/.drirc: No such file or directory.
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 0.0
    Max compat profile version: 2.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/strieder/.drirc: No such file or directory.
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 13.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

-

And glxgears:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears 
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/user/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 8086:2a42, driver i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/user/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Using DRI3 for screen 0
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/user/.drirc: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: What’s going on with that screenshot?

Comment: Can you see what is behind it? That's the problem, it's transparent. It should be displayng OpenGL content there. I added a link to the Qt example.

Comment: Yes; It looks like you have an XWindow session open to your own desktop session.  What processor do you have.  That would determine what OpenGL versions are supported

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     L9400  @ 1.86GHz, 4GB ram. What does it mean to have a XWindow session open to your own desktop session, is it good? I tried the same on vmware instead of this machine and it works.

Comment: I have only ever used Xsession to make remote sessions to a computer

Comment: This fresh install.  You have performed an update and install the appropriate Intel display drivers?

Comment: Oh sure, is not that resh anymore, gonna correct that.